# c# нет класса System.Web.Http

Tags: c#

использую .NET 4.5 в Visual Studio 2012, Win7 x64.  почему то System.Web не содержит Http класс. что нужно еще установить?

Comment: может потому что такого класса вообще нет? `System.Web.Http` - это неймспейс, а не класс.

Comment: `using System.Web.Http;`

Comment: В том и дело. Пишу using System.Web.Http; подчеркивает красным

Comment: @axmed2004  потому что [System.Web.Http](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.http(v=vs.118).aspx) в фреймворке **ASP.NET Web API 2**, и поскольку в тегах вашего вопроса его нет, рискну предположить что у нас тут маленькое недопонимание :) вы какое приложение разрабатываете: WPF, WinForms, ASP.Net ? в каждом случае свои немного разные аналоги, что из пространства `Http` вам требуется?

Comment: @axmed2004  может вам [System.Net.Http](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.http(v=vs.118).aspx) на самом деле нужен?)

Comment: Делаю HTTP сервер на wpf, для обработки get post запросов. Типа этого http://www.sources.ru/csharp/SimpleHttpServer.html

Comment: @axmed2004 когда отвечаете на комментарии пишите в начале @ИмяАдресата, иначе у него уведомления не будет; мне кажется вам нужно `using System.Net;` использовать класс [HttpListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx), пример:["Для прослушивания подключений по протоколу HTTP и ответа на HTTP-запросы предназначен класс HttpListener..."](https://metanit.com/sharp/net/7.1.php)

Comment: @axmed2004 погодите ка, вашу правку не сразу обновил...

Comment: @axmed2004 хмм, ну чтож :) переходите на платформу ASP.Net, в приведённом вами примере классы `HttpServer` и пр. оттуда

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Подключите сборку `System.Web.Http` (она в System.Web.Http.dll)

Узнать, в какой сборке лежит тот или иной класс можно на MSDN, например: [HttpServer - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.http.httpserver(v=vs.118).aspx)

> **Пространство имен:**  System.Web.Http
>
> **Сборка:**  System.Web.Http (в System.Web.Http.dll)